# How to set image in imageView of a viewFlipper as a wallpaper?

Tags: android-studio

I am developing an android wallpaper app in which I am using a viewFlipper which contains different imageviews. I have sliding animation on viewFlipper, I want to set the current image shown in viewflipper as a wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

```
you should get the image and make it into bitmap at first. Once you have the bitmap of that image use the following :
WallpaperManager wallpaper = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
try{
    wallpaper.setBitmap(yourBitmap);
catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```